# error in solving acoupled,first order differential equations in ipython

Tags: scipy, ipython

### I have  a following coupled, first order differential equations:

1. dB(t)/dt=-a*A(t);
2. dA(t)/dt=b*B(t);
3. dJ(t)/dt=c*A(t)-d*B(t)

Solve the system using paramenters a = 0.05, b = 0.02, c = 0.03 and d = 0.04 of your own choice over a time interval from 0 to 200. 
Here is my code:

```
a=0.05
b=0.02
c=0.03
d=0.04

def function(x,t):
    x1, x2, x3 = x[0], x[1], x[2]
    #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
    dx1=b*x1
    dx2=-a*x0
    dx3=c*x0-d*x1
    return [dx1, dx2, dx3]
x0 = [100,100, 1]
t = linspace(0, 200, 200)
x = odeint(function, x0, t)
```

---

The output I got is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f8f398346307> in function(x, t)
      8     #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      9     dx1=b*x1
---> 10     dx2=-a*x0
     11     dx3=c*x0-d*x1
     12     return [dx1, dx2, dx3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Repeated convergence failures (perhaps bad Jacobian or tolerances).
Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
```

---

what is the problem of my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have fixed it.

```
    a=0.05
    b=0.02
    c=0.03
    d=0.04

    def function(x,t):
      x1, x2, x3 = x[0], x[1], x[2]
      #x1, x2, x3 = A, B, J
      dx1=b*x2 
      dx2=-a*x1
      dx3=c*x1-d*x2
      return [dx1, dx2, dx3]
   x0 = [100,100, 1]
   t = linspace(0, 200, 200)
   x = odeint(function, x0, t)
```

Answer (score 1):

- You have three *first-order* equations, not second order. (Or did you mean to write second order derivatives in your equations 1, 2, and 3?)
- `deriv` should return the three values dA/dt, dB/dt and dJ/dt, but currently it returns an array of length 5.
- `zinit` should contain three values: A(0), B(0) and J(0).